# How to receive phone call events

Tags: java

The application I'm developing needs to receive events from a SAP Contact Center for interactions happening on phones. Events such as *IciEvent_phoneCallChanged*, for example.

I am already able to receive user events by sending a subscription request. I am sending a subscription request for the Container interface and it **seems** to be working. In Wireshark I can see the response coming back from the Contact Centre, but when I make test calls no events are received.

The Container subscription is as such

```
containerSubscriber = new ContainerSubscriber("urn:IciContainerInterface", "IciContainerService", "http://<client_address>/oii/icicontainerservice.asmx?wsdl");

IciContainerServiceSoap port = containerSubscriber.getPort();
com.dvsoft.sap.containerici.client.SubscribeResponseResponse response = port.subscribe(appURL, appIdContainer, "1", container);



public class ContainerSubscriber {

    private QName SERVICE_NAME;
    private String wsdlurl;

    public ContainerSubscriber(String namespaceURI, String localPart, String wsdlurl) {
        this.wsdlurl = wsdlurl;
        SERVICE_NAME = new QName(namespaceURI, localPart);
    }

    public IciContainerServiceSoap getPort() {
        IciContainerServiceSoap port = null;
        try {
            URL wsdlURL;
            wsdlURL = new URL(wsdlurl);
            IciContainerService service = new IciContainerService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);

            port = service.getIciContainerServiceSoap();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return port;

    }
}
```

So....

How do I correctly subscribe for and receive phonecall events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it *seemed* to be working is that it was working. I was doing everything correctly on my side. The problem was that the user I was given to test with wasn't added to the correct group/queue so events weren't being sent.